# Traversing through DOM through PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am traversing through a given `DOM` through `PHP`.  I am using php `DOMdocument` class to traverse through it. What I have done so far is I traverse through all the DOM and I am able to get the `nodeValue` of each element. But what i want to do is to detect, if the child a `DOM` element have children add a `&nbsp` space before the node value of each children. But this space should be equal  for all siblings like :

- Parent

  - child
  - child
  - child

    - subchild
    - subchild

      - grandsubchild
      - grandsubchild
  - child
  - child

This is what I have done :

```js
$html = "<body>
 I am the Boss
 <div>
  I am Nadeem
  <div>
   I am Rayyan and child of Nadeem
   <ul>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
    <li>I am child of Rayyan</li>
   </ul>
   <div>
    I am child of Rayyan  and sibling of his children
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   I am Mehroyan and Child of Nadeem
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  I am Faisal, Sibling of Nadeem
  <h2>
   I am Adnan and child of Faisal
   <a >I am child of Adnan</a>
  </h2>
 </div>
 <div>
  I am Saud
  <span>
   I am Zohaib son of Saud
   <ul>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib</li>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib</li>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib and Sibling as well</li>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib and Sibling as well</li>
    <li>I am son of Zohaib and Sibling as well</li>
   </ul>
  </span>
  <span>
   I am Zaryab son of Saud and sibling of Zohaib
   <div>
    I am Zaryab Son
    <h4>
     I am Zaryab Grandson
     <a > I am Zaryab Grand Grand Son</a>
    </h4>
   </div>
  </span>
 </div>
</body>";




$document = new DOMdocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$document->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $document->getElementsByTagName("body");

$GLOBALS['i'] =  1;

function traverseDom($element){
 
  if($element->hasChildNodes()){
          
          foreach($element->childNodes as $child){
             $GLOBALS['i']++;
             traverseDom($child);
          }

  } 

  else{
             
   echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $GLOBALS['i']).$element->nodeValue."<br>";

  }

}

foreach($elements as $element){
   traverseDom($element);
}
```

Comment: When you run this , you will get the output, and then you can see the spaces given @NigelRen

Comment: Sorry - the XML is badly formatted :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your using a GLOBAL value to keep track of the spaces to use, this only ever gets incremented.  The alternative is to pass in a 'level' to each level, this determines the output number of spaces.  I've also used `trim()` to remove any padding round the content.

```
$document = new DOMdocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $document-> getElementsByTagName("body");

function traverseDom($level, $element) {
    if ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($element->childNodes as $child) {
            traverseDom($level+1, $child);
        }
    } else {
        $out = trim($element->nodeValue);
        if ( !empty($out) ) {
            echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $level).$out."<br>";
        }
    }
}

foreach($elements as $element) {
    traverseDom(0, $element);
}
```